# How can I find y?

Tags: exponential-function, functional-equations

The following equation is given: $$ye^y=e^{x+1}$$ when $x=0$. I tried to solve it as logarithmic equation but I can't go further. I know $y=1$ but I don't know how to prove it. Any idea? Thank you

Comment: Indeed, someone has thought if this problem before: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Comment: You are saying that $ye^y=e^{x+1}$ holds for $x=0$ so that $ye^y=e^1=e$? But then, $y=1$ obviously is a solution.

Comment: "I know $y=1$ but I don't know how to prove it": what about $1e^1=e^{0+1}$ ? :-)

Comment: There is no real need to introduce $x$ then set it to $0$.

Comment: I found it! It's right there at the beginning of your equation!

Answer (score 3):

You may write

- $ye^y = e^{\ln y + y} = e^{x+1} \Rightarrow \ln y + y = 1+x \stackrel{x= 0}{\Rightarrow} \Rightarrow \ln y + y = 1 \Rightarrow y =1$

The uniqueness of the solution follows from the monotonicity of $\ln y+ y$.

Comment: Can't you just say that $ye^y$ is monotonic ?

Comment: Yes, of course. But I just said that $\ln y + y$ is monotonic. :-)
Even if this gives me a downvote as I have just seen :-D. Funny.

Comment: I can't understand the need to take the logarithm...

Comment: I thought MSE is a place where the OPs can see different answers to their questions and may decide for themselves what is most helpful for them. The shortest solution is not always the most helpful depending on the knowledge of the OP.

Comment: I mean that I don't see in what way the logarithm simplifies the resolution.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this equation by taking logarithms both side with respect to the base $e$.
The equation becomes:
$$\ln(ye^y)=\ln(e^{x+1})$$
$$\ln y+\ln e^y=\ln (e^{x+1})$$
$$\ln y +y = x+1$$
You are given the value of $x=0$, put it in the equation to get:
$$\ln y +y =1$$

From the equation, if we put $y=1$ it satisfies the equation. You can also plot a graph for the two functions.

[image]

Hope this helps...

Comment: "You can solve this equation by taking logarithms both side": this doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

If $x=0$, then $y=1$ is obviously a solution. But $e^{x+1}=e\cdot e^x>e^x$, and $x+1>x$, hence $xe^x$ is an increasing function. Since $y=1$ solves $ye^y=e$, and $e$ is constant, it is unique.